# How to create virtualenv python when getting the error mentioned below .?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am new to Django, I am creating Virtual environment for the new project, I was able to do it for first time, so i have deactivated virtual environment, deleted the whole folder recreate again. Then I am getting errors as mentioned below. How to fix these error?

I have deleted the folder, opened a new command prompt, I have tried to create the virtualenv in another drive(D:) still getting the same errors. I have used the following commands to get it work 'virtualenv .' and 'virtualenv python3 .'

```
C:\Programming\Django>virtualenv .

C:\users\asus\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\distutils\__init__.py:14: UserWarning: The virtualenv distutils package at %s appears to be in the same location as the system distutils?
warnings.warn("The virtualenv distutils package at %s appears to be in the same location as the system distutils?")
 Using real prefix 'c:\\users\\asus\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python37'
New python executable in D:\Programming\Django\Scripts\python.exe
Command D:\Programming\Django\Scripts\python.exe -m pip config list had error code 1
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\asus\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", mod_spec)
  File "c:\users\asus\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  
  File "C:\Users\ASUS\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\Scripts\virtualenv.exe\__main__.py", line 9, in <module>
  
  File "c:\users\asus\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\virtualenv.py", line 793, in main
    symlink=options.symlink,
  
  File "c:\users\asus\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\virtualenv.py", line 1088, in create_environment
    install_wheel(to_install, py_executable, search_dirs, download=download)
  
  File "c:\users\asus\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\virtualenv.py", line 935, in install_wheel
    _install_wheel_with_search_dir(download, project_names, py_executable, search_dirs)
  
  File "c:\users\asus\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\virtualenv.py", line 964, in _install_wheel_with_search_dir
    config = _pip_config(py_executable, python_path)
  
  File "c:\users\asus\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\virtualenv.py", line 1043, in _pip_config
    config[key] = ast.literal_eval(value)
  
  File "c:\users\asus\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\ast.py", line 46, in literal_eval
    node_or_string = parse(node_or_string, mode='eval')
 
  File "c:\users\asus\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\ast.py", line 35, in parse
    return compile(source, filename, mode, PyCF_ONLY_AST)
  
  File "<unknown>", line 1
    real_distutils.__version__
    ^
IndentationError: unexpected indent
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe the issue is that your new virtual environment is on D:\ drive, but your general python is on the C:\ drive, and is what you're trying to build from. Although it would be a little odd if this is true (because of how virtual env's are configured), it is possible; it would be like saying start your car without fuel.

The reason I believe this is the problem is because your Traceback error traces back to the C:\ drive, but your virtual environment isn't configured for that, or vice versa. You can see what I mean if we format your logs.

- D:\Programming\Django\Scripts\python.exe -m pip config list had error code 1 **Traceback** (most recent call last):

  - File "c:\users\asus\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main "main", mod_spec)
  - File "c:\users\asus\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code exec(code, run_globals)
  - File "C:\Users\ASUS\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\Scripts\virtualenv.exe__main__.py", line 9, in File "c:\users\asus\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\virtualenv.py", line 793, in main symlink=options.symlink, File "c:\users\asus\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\virtualenv.py", line 1088, in create_environment install_wheel(to_install, py_executable, search_dirs, download=download)
  - File "c:\users\asus\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\virtualenv.py", line 935, in install_wheel _install_wheel_with_search_dir(download, project_names, py_executable, search_dirs) File "c:\users\asus\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\virtualenv.py", line 964, in _install_wheel_with_search_dir config = _pip_config(py_executable, python_path)
  - File "c:\users\asus\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\virtualenv.py", line 1043, in _pip_config config[key] = ast.literal_eval(value) File "c:\users\asus\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\ast.py", line 46, in literal_eval node_or_string = parse(node_or_string, mode='eval')
  - File "c:\users\asus\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\ast.py", line 35, in parse return compile(source, filename, mode, PyCF_ONLY_AST) File "", line 1 real_distutils.version ^ IndentationError: unexpected indent

Because you referenced Django, here is their install guide for windows, just in case. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/howto/windows/. If you followed the guide exactly, I would confidently say the issue is not with your environment, and something with your pip install of Django. Maybe try uninstall and reinstall?

Hope this helps! Do let us know what you find.

Comment: First I was doing in C drive in the same folder structure which I have done in D drive, as I thought as I have already created in the C drive and deleted, might creating a problem. So I was trying in D drive. And will surely try from the url you have shared, thank you for the quick help

Comment: This is wrong and there is definitely no reason why a virtual environment couldn't be created on a different drive vs. the base Python installation. The error is clearly coming from an attempt to `ast.literal_eval` a string that has leading whitespace.